# Google Sheets API: insert formatted text

Tags: node.js, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am trying to insert bolded text into Google Spreadsheet. I have the following NodeJS code that inserts the text successfully.

```
var body = {
 data: [{
   range: 'M2:M3',
   values: [["value1"],["value2"]]
 }],
 valueInputOption: 'USER_ENTERED',
};

var sheets = google.sheets('v4');
  sheets.spreadsheets.values.batchUpdate({
    auth: auth,
    spreadsheetId: SPREADSHEET_ID,
    resource: body
  }, function(err, response) {
    if (err) {
      console.log('The API returned an error: ' + err);
      return;
    }
  });
```

I looked up and found that in order to change the text format to bold, the following code needs to be used.

```
requests: [
 {
   "format": {
     "textFormat": {
       "bold": true
      }
   }
 }
]
```

However, I cannot understand where this code should go. Tried putting `requests` as well as `format` separately inside `data` and `batchUpdate` but it did not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this sample script? If you want to update cell values and cell format, simultaneously, you can use spreadsheets.batchUpdate. The detail information is [here](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate).

The following sample imports `[["value1"],["value2"]]` to `'M2:M3'` as shown in your script. As a sample, Sheet id is 0. The range is required to be inputted the [GridRange](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets#gridrange).

#### Sample script :

```
var sheets = google.sheets('v4');
var request = {
  spreadsheetId: SPREADSHEET_ID,
  resource: {
    "requests": [
      {
        "updateCells": {
          "rows": [
            {
              "values": [
                {
                  "userEnteredValue": {
                    "stringValue": "value1"
                  },
                  "userEnteredFormat": {
                    "textFormat": {
                      "bold": true
                    }
                  }
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "values": [
                {
                  "userEnteredValue": {
                    "stringValue": "value2"
                  },
                  "userEnteredFormat": {
                    "textFormat": {
                      "bold": true
                    }
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          ],
          "range": {
            "sheetId": 0, // Sheet id
            "startColumnIndex": 12,
            "endColumnIndex": 13,
            "startRowIndex": 1,
            "endRowIndex": 3
          },
          "fields": "*"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  auth: auth,
};
sheets.spreadsheets.batchUpdate(request, function(err, response) {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err);
    return;
  }
  console.log(JSON.stringify(response, null, 2));
});
```

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.