# Format Google Sheet text in Java

Tags: java, google-sheets-api, google-api-java-client, text-formatting

I'm using the Google sheet API, version 4, to write to a spreadsheet. It's working good, but I need to format the text (bold, underline,...) and I can't seem to find any way to do this using the Google Java API client.

I know this is feasible by requesting via GET and POST to http://sheets.googleapis.com but I already developed it with the Java client and I would really appreciate not having to build up everything again.

Does anyone have any thoughts on this?

Just in case it was not clear enough, I'm using the Java Google Sheet client

Comment: What do you mean? Of course you have the ability to format text via the API.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Sheets API: insert formatted text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46887417/google-sheets-api-insert-formatted-text)

Comment: how is this a duplicate if this question is about java and the other one node.js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using the CellData class it's possible to format the cell with background colors, font family, size and many other options. This is an example of how to use it:

```
    CellData setUserEnteredValue = new CellData()
            .setUserEnteredValue(new ExtendedValue().setStringValue("example text"));

    CellFormat cellFormat = new CellFormat();
    cellFormat.setTextFormat(new TextFormat().setBold(true));

    setUserEnteredValue.setUserEnteredFormat(cellFormat);
```

Here's a link to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/sheets/v4/java/latest/com/google/api/services/sheets/v4/model/CellFormat.html)

Comment: Can you please tell a way to get the Font color of a cell value.

Comment: Sorry, it's been too long ago I used this and I didn't have to get the font color of a cell value. You should better ask this in a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Making top row BOLD:

```
    RepeatCellRequest repeatCellRequest = new RepeatCellRequest();
    CellData cellData = new CellData();
    CellFormat cellFormat = new CellFormat();
    TextFormat textFormat = new TextFormat();
    textFormat.setBold(true);
    cellFormat.setTextFormat(textFormat);
    cellData.setUserEnteredFormat(cellFormat);
    repeatCellRequest.setCell(cellData);
    repeatCellRequest.setFields("userEnteredFormat(textFormat)");
    GridRange gridRange = new GridRange();
    gridRange
        .setSheetId(0)
        .setStartRowIndex(0)
        .setEndRowIndex(1);
    repeatCellRequest.setRange(gridRange);
    List<Request> requests = new ArrayList<>();
    requests.add(new Request().setRepeatCell(repeatCellRequest));
    BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest body2 = new BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest().setRequests(requests);
    sheets.spreadsheets().batchUpdate(spreadsheetId, body2).execute();
```